# Error in receiving JavaScript value in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am writing a simple code to select a radio button and pass the value of the selected radio to php code, through AJAX!

Heres my code for AJAX:

```
function sendid(attack)
{
    var att;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","battlephp.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("att="+attack+"");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="radio" value="10" name="attack" onclick="sendid('this.value')"/> Attack 1
<input type="radio" value="20" name="attack" onclick="sendid('this.value')"/> Attack 2
```

And my php code:

```
$attack = intval($_POST['att']);
echo "Working ".$attack;
```

The Output I am getting is:

```
Working 0
```

Which should be either "Working 10" or "Working 20"

Surely its not identifying the att which is passed through the AJAX..! But how should I handle it now??

Comment: What do you get if *don't* convert it to an integer? (show us var_export($_POST, true); )

Comment: getting nothing..! that same error appearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be

```
<input type="radio" value="10" name="attack" onclick="sendid(this.value)"/> Attack 1
<input type="radio" value="20" name="attack" onclick="sendid(this.value)"/> Attack 2
```

You should not enclose `this.value` with `'` single quotes since it will consider it as string if you enclose with single quotes rather than object property

Comment: have you tried in console, what actually is passing to server, use firebug or developer console

Comment: sorry i have never used it! so do not have idea how to use it? :\ ifu can tell me how can i check the passing parameter.. i will do so

Comment: If you are using firefox right click -> Inspect Element -> Network , similar way in chrome. You can see the actual requests sent to server. Check it and let me know what data is actually sent to server via ajax

Comment: when you click on one of the row in network you'll see a tab in the right side with menu as params.. check that